# Getting a JVM Crash error. Possible Memory error

Tags: java, jvm

So I am getting the most random JVM crashes while my Web Application is in production. My environment is Linux Redhat enterprise edition 7, Jboss AS 7, Java 8, JSF 2.2

This crash seems to happen when my user persists some data to the database. Here is the **JVM** log:

Here is a link to my full log it exceeded the maximum character amount to post on this site.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JrHFckYWh5d2ktRGphUTJlRFk/view?usp=sharing

I have no idea what is relevant, this has been happening a lot recently I have a hunch it's because of too little memory allocated somewhere, I appreciate the help,

Sam

Comment: This indicates either a bug in the JVM itself, a bug in some JNI code you are invoking (could be in your code or a 3rd party library), or (if it's happening a lot at different places) a hardware problem.

Comment: please, provide full crash report

Answer (score 0):

Crash seems to be Kernel related issue, Please find the complete blog details here https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/analysis_of_strange_hotspot_crashes 
Form your logs it is not clear which kernel version you are using, logs are missing System information. Please upgrade your kernel version. FInd the similar issue here - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161645

Comment: I'm not using openJdk

Comment: @Sam_in_real_life could you please share complete hs_error file? OpenJDk and the one JRE you are using it is from same source Oracle (Java HotSpot(TM))

Answer (score 0):

Crash occurs somewhere in code cache while trying to run this:

`J 12713 C2 com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR.update([BII[BI)I (158 bytes)`.
I found similar bug in openjdk's jira and it says that `-XX:-UseAESIntrinsics` can help you.
Also you can exclude this method from JIT compilation `-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/sun/crypto/provider/GCTR.update`